# Utilizando o Count com select all

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou querendo fazer um sql contando os registros com duplicidade:

```
select produto,matricula,data,fornecedor, count(*) from tb_teste 
 group by produto,matricula 
 order by fornecedor
```

Dessa forma da erro, o sql requisita os campos `data,fornecedor` porém não posso agrupar por eles também.

Comment: `select produto,matricula,data,fornecedor, count(*) from tb_teste 
 group by produto,matricula,data,fornecedor
 order by fornecedor`

Comment: Se não interessam a data e o fornecedor então retire tais campos da query.

Comment: @anonimo claro que interessa mas não quero agrupar por esses campos.

Comment: @Marconi exatamente isso que eu não posso fazer é colocar no group by a data e o fornecedor.

Comment: por que você precisa de `data` e `fornecedor`? conceitualmente **não é possível o `count(*)` sem trazer os demais campos do _select_ no agrupamento**.

Comment: Se para cada produto e matrícula puder existir mais de uma data e/ou fornecedor, e você não quer considera-los, então qual deles você sorteará para exibir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode sempre tentar da forma abaixo:

```
SELECT      TT.produto
        ,   TT.matricula
        ,   TT.data
        ,   TT.fornecedor
        ,   TT.contador
FROM        tb_teste    TT
INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT      COUNT(1) AS contador
                        ,   produto
                        ,   matricula
                FROM        tb_teste
                GROUP BY    produto
                        ,   matricula
            )           TT2 ON  TT2.produto     = TT.produto
                            AND TT2.matricula   = TT.matricula
WHERE       TT2.contador > 1
ORDER BY    TT.fornecedor
```

Mas assim só terá a ligação pelo produto e matrícula, não sei se será o suficiente.

Da forma que queria fazer inicialmente é impossível. Se quer contar os registos com base em determinados campos, todos eles têm de estar no `GROUP BY` senão não conseguirá executar a *query*.

Comment: se eu quiser trazer o total(count) de registros duplicados, nessa mesma consulta.

Comment: Nesse caso basta colocar um COUNT(1) no SELECT e remover todos os outros campos. O ORDER BY também será desnecessário e pode ser removido. Se a resposta está correta ou se lhe foi útil, marque-a pf :)